# Injecting an object into UIViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to inject an object into a UIViewController from the AppDelegate but I am not sure that I am doing it correctly.  Please can someone advise.  I get an error when I start my application at the line of code marked 'THE ERROR OCCURS HERE'.

[image]

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Create ItemStore instance
    let itemStoreObject = ItemStore()


    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let testController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testTableController") as! TestTableViewController
    testController.itemstore = itemStoreObject

    return true
}
```

ItemStore:

```
 import UIKit

 class ItemStore {

var allItems = ["Thanh", "David", "Tommy", "Maria"]
```

}

TestTableViewController:

```
 class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
var itemstore: ItemStore!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsSection ...")
    return itemstore.allItems.count // THE ERROR OCCURS HERE. 
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRow ...")
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    let name = itemstore.allItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = name

    return cell
}

}
```

I get the following error message (marked in the line 'THE ERROR OCCURS HERE'):

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
 (lldb)
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't initialized the `itemstore` object

Comment: it seems you didn't set `testController` as `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate a view controller in `AppDelegate`, but the system will create another instance of that view controller class and hence display an instance of the class that has no itemstore property initialised.
You either have to make `itemstore` a type variable instead of an instance variable or if you only need this functionality for your root view controller, you have to instantiate the `itemstore` variable for your root view controller instance, which you know will be the one used by your navigation controller.

Comment: So you mean I should just instantiate an ItemStore instance in my TestTableViewController?

Comment: No. If you get the data needed to instantiate an `ItemStore` instance in AppDelegate, you need to pass that object to the `TestTableViewController` that is in your Navigation controller's view hierarchy. To achieve this you have to do one of the two methods I suggested in my answer.